# article, section or div for list of products?

Tags: html

I'm currently working on an ecommerce project and can't work out whether to use article, section or a div to wrap the product listing.

There are multiple sections following it for things such as promos and I don't want to use div since the following sections would have a greater meaning and undermine it, however it should have a greater meaning than the following sections.

[image: Image of layout]

I'm considering the article tag but I cannot find an example of it being used outside of a blog. I've noticed people deem it acceptable for single items (product pages), but what approach should be used for browsing product listings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`section` specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) is very instructive:

> The `section` element represents a generic document or application section. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading, possibly with a footer.
>
> Note: The `section` element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the `div` element instead.

If a number of elements are thematically related and can be grouped together under a common title (e.g. "Shoes") then wrap the products in a `section`.

If the elements you are wrapping are not related, cannot be grouped under a common title and are just being wrapped for the purpose of styling then use a `div`.

For completeness, the [`article`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element) tag represents (from the same page):

> a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

so your items for sale would each be an `article` within the `section`.

As a final side note, I wouldn't wrap the whole page in a `<div role="main">`: surely the header sits *outside* of the main content.

Comment: Good call, that seems pretty logical (the <div role=main> doesn't encompass the entire page, another header and more content precedes it, apologies I should have shown this in the image).

Comment: Fair enough. I'm glad this is helpful - I'm only just learning about all these HTML5 elements myself. It seems that deciding on which to use isn't helped by the fact that the standard is only a draft: specifications change and we can expect further (hopefully minor) changes for a while.